# How to force tabs to mount without ever clicking on the tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Using React & material-ui, I have a pretty big tab container and want to keep data fetches local to each Tab component. I want to be able to essentially greedy load some of the Tab components so as soon as the Tab container is mounted, the Tabs with a greedyLoad prop passed to them are mounted (although not the active tab/visible) and make the fetch for the data they need.

The reason is some of the tabs need a count from the data I fetch in the tab label.

I understand I can fetch the data from the parent component and pass the data as a prop downwards, but I really would like to keep the fetch’s local to each tab component. I’ve seen it done at a previous company I worked at and totally forgot how it worked. Something with CSS I think. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you hide the component with CSS, your component will mount on the DOM, but it will be invisible to the user. We just need to add some inline css and make use of the [display: none](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp#:%7E:text=%3Cimg%3E-,Display%3A%20none%3B,-display%3A%20none%3B) property

```
 function myComponent(show) {
    // TODO: fetch the data
    return (
      <div style={{display: show ? "block" : "none"}}>
        <h1 >This component may be invisible!</h1>
          <p>{data}</p>
      </div>
    );
}
```